# HTML table with row spans

Tags: html, html-table

How can I make a table layout like below in HTML?

```
-------------------------------
|      2        |    1 row    |
|     rows      |-------------|
|---------------|      2      |
|    1 row      |    rows     |
-------------------------------
```

Comment: show us your effort?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to set height for each cell in columns. And use rowspan attribute.

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" height="80">2 rows</td>
    <td height="40">1 row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" height="80">2 rows</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="40">1 row</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```